# SAP Hybris, is there any OOB approach to define length for collection for one-to-many relations in itemType?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

is there any OOB approach to define length for collection for one-to-many relations in itemType or I have to handle it via interceptor?

I have to create two CMS Component, with one to many relationship. e.g 1st CMS Component **A** and other CMS Component **Apanel**. **A** cms component can hold only 4 **Apanel** cms component?

Note able to find any specific solution, otherthan using interceptor.

Comment: Maybe you can add 4 separate fields.

Comment: That can be work around, Thank you :)

Comment: If you need this validation only backoffice, you can use dynamic constraint.